# Do I need to synchronize ArrayList of Sockets?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, synchronization

I have an ArrayList of sockets, and I am using multiple threads. Do I need to declare the list as Collections.synchronizedList and then call synchronized(listName) each time I want to iterate the list? What about adding new sockets to the list with listName.add(socket)? Do I need to synchronize that call also?

Server Class

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server implements Runnable {

    private int listenPort;
    private int maxClients;
    private int clientNumber;
    private boolean isRunning;
    private ServerSocket listener;

    // Synchronize This?
    private ArrayList<Client> clients;

    public Server(int listenPort, int maxClients) throws IOException {
        this.listenPort = listenPort;
        this.maxClients = maxClients;
        this.clientNumber = 0;
        this.isRunning = true;

        this.listener = new ServerSocket(
                listenPort, maxClients,
                InetAddress.getLocalHost()
        );

        this.clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            try {
                Socket socket = listener.accept();
                Client client = new Client(socket, ++clientNumber);
                clients.add(client);

                new Thread(client).start();
            } catch (IOException ex) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The fact that you have multiple threads dictates that.

The fact that it contains `Sockets` has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Although in general case you should synchronize access to fields that can be accessed from different threads this is not necessarily in your particular case because you are accessing this collection in fact from one thread only. However if you are planning to continue development and access this collection from other threads @EJP is obviously right.

BTW at least in this code fragment you do not need this collection at all. You are opening thread per client. The thread will be alive until socket is open. Why do you need this collection?